# Using swagger with an android database

Tags: android, sqlite, mustache, swagger, greendao

I'm looking for away to use [Swagger](http://swagger.io) with an on-device database on android, ideally with [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com) and [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) but I'm willing to use what works.

The app will need to have a persistent database and also sync/communicate with a server that uses swagger. I'm looking for ways to use the code generation of swagger with an on-device database rather than defining the model manually.

Is there a swagger codegen library or project that will work with an android ORM (preferably greendao)? I haven't found anything yet, but haven't been looking too long.

Otherwise, I'm going to try making/modifying .mustache files for the model which work with DaoGenerator. It will likely require a two step process to update the model, but that's easier than recreating the model manually.

Open to other ideas and suggestions as well!

Comment: Is it an option to store the entire YAML or JSON as a string in your local datastore?

Comment: That may work for a relatively small dataset, but I'm hoping to find a solution that will work with large sets as well.

Comment: Maybe you should build your own codegen library and share it to the whole opensource community !